# How do you do this permutation?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How would you do this math problem? and how do you know to use the equation you use?

1. Mendy’s offers three types of bread: White, Whole-Wheat and Rye. The choices of meat are corned beef, pastrami, turkey, and roast beef. How many different sandwiches of one type of bread and one type of meat are possible?

Comment: For each type of bread, match a type of meat: $3\cdot4=12$.

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of bread. There are four types of meat. If there are no restrictions on the pairing other than that there can only be one meat and one bread, then the answer is given by the product of the two sets; hence $3\times 4 = 12$ different sandwiches.